inflight vulnerability in exceljs
exceljs@4.4.0 => archiver@5.3.2 => archiver-utils@2.1.0 => glob@7.2.3 => inflight@1.0.6
is there anyway for excel js to not use inflight, or is there any other library apart from exceljs and xlsx (also has vulnerabilities)? My use cases involves reading xlsx files and writing csv files  via react app.
I checked exceljs github repo, the issue created for this is open since months https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/2715.
